# Magento2 : How to add custom link in footer inside newsletter block?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, newsletter, footer

To add custom link in newsletter block magento 2 ??[image]

Answer (score 5):

For add custom link in footer inside newsletter block.You Need to override these file in your custom theme

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml.

like this one

> app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe $block */

?>
<div class="block newsletter">
    <div class="title">
        <strong>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Newsletter')) ?>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe"
            novalidate
            action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
            method="post"
            data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
            id="newsletter-validate-detail">
            <div class="field newsletter">
                <a href ="link">link</a>
                <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for sneak peaks and sales!')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter"
                            placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enter your email')) ?>"
                            data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button id="subscribe-button-click" class="action subscribe primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscribe')) ?>" type="submit">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscribe')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

You Add Link Whenever you want in subscribe block as per your html. i have add a link before the newsletter block.PLease check and let me know in case of any issue.

Answer (score 4):

you can override below file in your theme and update **footer container** also add custom link

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <body>
 <referenceContainer name="footer"> 
     <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe"> 
        <block class="vendor\module\Block\Navigation\Customer" after="-" name="vendor_accountr_footer" template="footer/custom.phtml"/> 
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link">
                <arguments>
                  <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Link</argument>
                  <!-- This will be displayed as the label of the link -->
                  <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/page</argument>
                  <!-- here give the path where the link redirect to -->
                </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock> 
 </referenceContainer> 
 </body> 
</page>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe">
                <block class="vendor\module\Block\Navigation\Customer" after="-" name="vendor_accountr_footer" template="footer/custom.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: i want to add link inside newsletter block in app/code itself

Comment: i have added first code this code worked code

Comment: Let me know if you have any confusion for implementation.

Comment: actually i dnt want to override template through design , just from code itself i need to add link inside newsletter block

Comment: see my layout i have given reference block name as newsletter but didntworked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90611/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-gomathi).

Comment: i have updated my answer you can check it

Answer (score 3):

Copy **subscribe.phtml** file form

```
vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/
```

and paste to you custom theme at following location

`app/design/frontend/<vendor name>/<theme name>/Magento_Newsletter/templates/`

Now add custom link to **subscribe.phtml** file

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

In order to call links and custom block in footer in magento 2.

So, the file which is used to define configurations of footer is `default.xml`. This file will be located under `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/`. This file calls on every page, that’s why we write code for footer in this file.

Below code is used to call custom links in footer :

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link">
<arguments>
  <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Link</argument>
  <!-- This will be displayed as the label of the link -->
  <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/page</argument>
  <!-- here give the path where the link redirect to -->
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Now If you want to add your own custom block and template inside the footer,
then below code will be used :

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```